# Procedure executes differently when imported than when run in its native module

Tags: python, callback, python-2.7, tkinter

I have this code:

```
def Annabeth():
    Annabeth= Tk()
    Annabeth.geometry('450x450')
    says = Label(Annabeth,text ='I was just making a general statement!')
    says.pack(side=BOTTOM)
     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/Geekman2/Pictures/Pictures/Annabeth.jpg'))
    image1 = Label(Annabeth,image=img)
    image1.pack()
    Annabeth.mainloop()
```

it resides in the module

```
rox
```

when I invoke

```
Annabeth()
```

my window comes up, it displays the image, and everything works fine.
and when, from another module I use the code

```
from rox import*
Annabeth()
```

it works just fine
but when I use this code

```
def callback():
     Annabeth()

game = Tk()
game.geometry('50x50+700+100')
Button1 = Button(game,text = '1',command =callback )
Button1.pack(side=LEFT)


game.mainloop()
```

The window displays, but the picture does not show up and I get the error

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

And for the life of me I cannot figure out what is causing this, apparently I'm not supposed to have more than one mainloop in a GUI program, but how am I supposed to do this then?

Comment: Never ever ever have more than one main loop in a GUI application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to instanciate `Tk()` several times in your program. You might consider using `Toplevel` if you want multiple windows.

By the way, it will solve your several mainloop issue since `Toplevel` instances will run in the same mainloop as `game`.

What happens exactly is that `ImageTk.PhotoImage` creates the image in the first Tcl/Tk interpreter that has been created. Thus, your label `image1` that run in a second Tcl/Tk instance can not reach the picture.

Comment: just being curious: is it really Tcl/Tk or just Tk?

Comment: Tcl is the host language of the Tk toolkit. Tkinter access Tk method through a Tcl interpreter (it literally perform Tcl `eval`). Thus, I would answer, just Tcl. However it might sound off-topic to only talk of Tcl in a Tkinter anwser.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware of that; thought that Tk might have its own interfaces.